# Positioning of my navigation bar changes when uploaded to domain

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

Here is the code i have for the navbar:

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <a href="archive.html" class="currentblue" class="stop" style="text-decoration: none">ARCHIVE</a>
    <a href="home.html" class="item" class="stop" style="text-decoration: none">HOME</a>
    <a href="contact.html" class="item" class="stop" style="text-decoration: none">CONTACT</a>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
/* NAV BAR */

.nav{
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav li{
    display: inline;
}

.nav a{
    display: inline-block;
}

.currentred{
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 3.0vw;
    padding: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
    font-family: Impact;
}

.currentred:hover{
    color: white;
}

.currentblue{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 3.0vw;
    padding: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
    font-family: Impact;
}

.currentblue:hover{
    color: white;
}

.item{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 3.0vw;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    font-family: Impact;
}

.item:hover{
    color: white;
}
/* END NAV BAR */
```

And for some reason the positioning of the nav bar changed when i uploaded it to my github repository which i am hosting my website from.

Here are pictures showing how it's supposed to look like, which is runnning from my local pc and the second picture shows how it looks like on the domain.

Any ideas of why this is happening?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq0Ml.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap is the culprit here. Because you are using bootstraps css it is automatically assigning some styles to your navigation class .nav. In this case it is being assigned a display: flex property that is causing your issue. You can either override this and enter display: block; o what I would recommend is to use a different class name other than .nav if you want to style your own navigation area.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the nav bar centered horizontally, you need to update the margin for the `nav` class to:

```
.nav {
    /* other styles */
    margin: 150px auto;
}
```

Using a single value of `margin: 150px` is setting the left and right margin to 150px, which I believe is resulting in the rendering issues. A value of `auto` for the left/right margin will center horizontally.